# TFS - What does changing encoding do?

Tags: encoding, tfs

In TFS 2012, if I right click a source-controlled file, go to Properties --> Advanced and then change the encoding from UTF8 to Windows 1252, does that actually modify the file or does it simply change the way TFS reads the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file contents will not be changed, only the encoding value in the metadata will be changed.  This setting will affect the way TFS treats the file during compare and merge operations, but changing that value should not change the content itself.

Comment: To add to that, sometimes when I check-in the code it complains that the encoding has changed, how does the encoding change on its own?

Comment: @Isaiah4110 TFS uses a heuristic (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/09/10/463281.aspx), but that may not be up to date) to determine the encoding; changes to the file content could lead to the heuristic giving a different answer.

Comment: It does, however, affect how the contents of the file are transcoded into [the `Content` property of a `TfvcItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.itemmodel.content#microsoft-teamfoundation-sourcecontrol-webapi-itemmodel-content) when they are retrieved by the TFVC Client API.